# Java Swings: Is there any provision to add a close button to popup window?

Tags: java, swing

How can we add a close button on the Pop up window  similar to a JFrame on the right corner so that we can close that popup by clicking on it?

Thanks for the help

Comment: create your own popup.

Comment: Meaning it is not possible with JPopupmenu?

Comment: there is no reason why this should be possible with a JPopupMenu

Comment: Why do you want such a button? You can close any JPopupMenu by clicking anywhere outside the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own PopMenu by extanding JPopupMenu. By adding an action listener to the button you can react with anything you want(for example closing popup). Here is an example:

```
public class TestPopupMenu extends JPopupMenu {

private JLabel testLabel;
private JButton testButton;

public TestPopupMenu() {
    super();
    initMenuItems();
}

private void initMenuItems() {
    add(getTestLabel());
    add(getTestButton());       
}

private JButton getTestButton() {
    if (testButton == null) {
        testButton = new JButton("Test");
        testButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Do something what you want                   
            }
        });
    }
    return testButton;
}

private JLabel getTestLabel() {
    if (testLabel == null) {
        testLabel = new JLabel("#Some text");           
    }
    return testLabel;
}  }
```